# Creating phonegap app with youtube api integrated

Tags: cordova, youtube-api

I am trying to find a good guide where i can make something like this:

http://yougapi.com/products/mobile/youtube_mobile/

I am using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

I think Youtube is a very interesting site and i would very much like to create some kind of APP through Phonegap that can do somewhat of the link above shows.

Comment: No one knows a goog tut? :)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i know this site already, im looking for a tutorial/guide as i states in my question.

Comment: There are some nice getting started tutorials for JS on the official google documentation.. you want more?

Comment: I guess i give that a shot :)

Comment: Actually i havent been looking to much around on just that site u posted, but i figured it would take to much time, but it seems its quite easy.  So make a answer F481.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Here you can find some nice "Getting started tutorials" in the official documentation of Google.
There are also some parts espacially for JS.

Answer (score 0):

You already tried check the code behind the page and check [js file](http://yougapi.com/products/mobile/youtube_mobile/include/js/script.js)?

I think that you solve your problems using something like the js file.

Comment: Yea i did look at it there is some .php file that the JS refers to.  I took it when i read it that, this file i couldent get, and it was some sort of licenced file that costed real money

Comment: Sorry, I don't saw that it's paid.

Comment: Yea i was about to use that file myself hehe, but then i got nothing.  :(